# Close on click anywhere

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following script which works almost perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/uUAqe/

I just need it to have 1 added ability where any dropdown will automatically close no matter where on the page the user clicks, be it on a blank part of the page, on a button, in a textbox etc etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see an updated jsFiddle page here: http://jsfiddle.net/KYqyU/

To explain what is done, firstly, you bind an click event to the document that will hide the navigation drop-downs.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
    $('.navigation').removeClass("active");
});
```

Then after that, you modify the click event on the `.navigation` class to `return false` which stops the document event from propagating and hiding the navigation in this instance.

```
$('.navigation').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.navigation.active').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

As Mark also points out, you can use `event.StopPropagation()` to stop the propagation. If you use this method you will need to pass `event` into the click callback function as an argument/parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out to hide the navigation...

```
$('.navigation').click(function(event) {
    $(this).siblings('.navigation.active').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(event) {
    $('.navigation.active').click();
    $('.navigation').removeClass("active");
});
```

This uses [event.StopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) which stops any events from bubbling up the dom.  Since we only what to trigger the hide when `.navigation` is not the element clicked.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/uUAqe/3/).