# Close a menu with an anywhere click

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

As you guys can see, I have a drop down menu.

I have a lot of columns, each one has an option to open the menu.

```
$(".optionCont").live("click", function(){
    $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();
    if ($(this).next().css("display") == "none") {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
    }
});
```

So, how can I do the menu slideUp when I click in any place of the page?

Like a document click?

I visited others topics, but I don't know why, this is not working. Maybe I'm doing it in a diferent way.

I accept any tips in the menu coding.

Demo: [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CjWBQ/4/)

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  Check out the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104309/close-on-click-anywhere

Comment: @Adam: Cast a close vote then.

Comment: Hmm, guess I don't see any "close" vote option... Haven't done that before, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: yeah, i know that have others topics with some solution, but with me, dos not work that. sry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Register a *one-off* handler *inside* the callback to make sure the next click closes the menu:

```
$(".optionCont").live("click", function(ev){
    $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();
    if($(this).next().css("display") == "none"){
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }else{
        $(this).next().slideUp();
    }
    ev.stopPropagation();

    $(document).one('click', function() {
             $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();

    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/GcxMs/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".optionCont").click(function(e){
    $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();
    if($(this).next().css("display") == "none"){
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }else{
        $(this).next().slideUp();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

$(document).click(function() {
     $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjWBQ/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   if ($(e.target) != myEl)
       myEl.slideUp();
})
```

Alternative: [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CjWBQ/21/).

Source:

```
$(".optionCont").live("click", function(e) {
    var that = this;
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(that);
        if (e.target != that) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();
        }
    });
    if ($(this).next().css("display") === "none") {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').bind("click",function (){
    $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();
});
$('.dropMenuCont').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I think a better idea to check if something is hidden is to toggle the class on your menu in a callback of the animation and then check it with `hasClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the click to `<body>`

```
$('body').click(function() {
  $(".dropMenuCont").slideUp();
});

$('.dropMenuCont').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```