# Need to close the div on clicking anywhere in the browser - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using CSS and Jquery i made a drop down like thing. (So that i can theme that thing according to my other sites).

**My problem is when i click on the div it list the things and when i click within the particular div it is closing. Else it doesn't closing. It's always open.**

**It should not be always open.**

**What should i want to do if the user clicks outside then the drop down thing must close or hide or display none... whatever....**

Any ideas will be grateful....

thanks in advance....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JQUERY TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Drupal.behaviors.assignment_report = function (context) {
      $(".selectbox-list").click(clickSelect);
      $(".custom-selectboxes-replaced-list li").click(clickSelectedItem);
    }

    function clickSelect() {
      $(".custom-selectboxes-replaced-list").toggle();
    }

    function clickSelectedItem() {
      var $ul = $(this).closest('ul');
      var curr_ul_class = ($ul.attr('class')); // ul class
      var curr_div_class = ($ul.prev().attr('class')); // div class
      if(curr_ul_class == 'custom-selectboxes-replaced-list' || curr_div_class == 'selectbox-list') {
        $(".selectbox-list").html($(this).html());
        $(".custom-selectboxes-replaced-list").toggle();
      }
    }
    </script>
    <div class="selectbox-list">
        <div class="topic-list-two">All</div>
    </div>
        <ul class="custom-selectboxes-replaced-list" style="display:none">
            <li value=0>All</li>
            <li value=1>Pending</li>
            <li value=3>completed</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762750/close-a-menu-with-a-anywhere-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the concept. Div will close if mouse is clicked anywhere outside, but will not close if click is made anywhere inside it.

```
var $div = $('#div');
$(document.body).click(function(){
    if (!$div.has(this).length) { // if the click was not within $div
        $div.hide();
    }
});
```