# Close the menu on click

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I want to close my menu by clicking on a link or when I click outside the menu. In the interest of keeping things nice and light, I don't want to use jQuery.

How do I do it?

```
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav__left">
    <h3><a href="#home">DenisMasot</a></h3>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" /><label class="burger" for="nav"></label>
  <ul  class="nav__right">
    <li class="active">
      <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3><a href="#about">À propos</a></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3><a href="#production">Réalisation</a></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hope this will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762750/close-a-menu-with-an-anywhere-click?rq=1)

Comment: here's something that might interest you: [Javascript on click hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515527/javascript-onclick-hide-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with DOM API using [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on document. You then need logic to find if the click target was on the menu or any of its elements, or somewhere else on the page.

`isDescendent()` borrowed from [How to check in Javascript if one element is contained within another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234979/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-one-element-is-contained-within-another)

The menu can then be hidden with `element.style.display = 'none'`

I would question motivation to not use jQuery, you'll be making a lot more work for yourself in the long run...

```js
var menu = document.querySelector("nav.nav");
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (menu != e.target && 
      ! isDescendant(menu, e.target)) {
    console.log("Clicked somewhere else");
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    checkbox.checked = false;
  }
  
}, false);

function isDescendant(parent, child) {
     var node = child.parentNode;
     while (node != null) {
         if (node == parent) {
             return true;
         }
         node = node.parentNode;
     }
     return false;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Rest of page...
</div>

<nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav__left">
      <h3><a href="#home">DenisMasot</a></h3>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><label class="burger" for="nav"></label>
    <ul  class="nav__right">
      <li class="active">
        <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3><a href="#about">À propos</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3><a href="#production">Réalisation</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Is it possible to uncheck the input when I click outside the menu?

Comment: @DenayM This wasn't part of original question, but I've updated my answer. You need to use the .checked property. This information is readily available on google... If my answer solves your problem please consider accepting it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one way, hope it helps

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.click').click(function() {
                $('.nav__right').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav__left">
      <h3><a href="#home">DenisMasot</a></h3>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><label class="burger" for="nav"></label>
  <button class="click">click me</button>
    <ul  class="nav__right">
      <li class="active">
        <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3><a href="#about">À propos</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3><a href="#production">Réalisation</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```