# Open Dropdown with hover and close menu when click a link use js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to use javasript to close a dropdownmenu when click an link.
I have a Dropdownmenu thats open with mouse:hover. Now i need a function that close the menu when click some link like "down1" from the menu. But i have no idea how to do.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.gap {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  background-color: #f47721;
  margin-top: 6%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.dropbt1 {
  background-color: #f47721;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f47721;
  /* min-width: 160px; */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content1 a {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content1 a:hover {
  background-color: #d86a1e
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="gap">
    <h3>Dropdownmenu</h3>

    <button class="dropbt1"><h3>please choose</h3></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1">
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down1</a>
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down2</a>
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to use javasript to close a dropdownmenu when click an link.
I have a Dropdownmenu thats open with mouse:hover. Now i need a function that close the menu when click some link like "down1" from the menu. But i have no idea how to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close the menu on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201156/close-the-menu-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

I have done sample code hope it will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.dropdown-content1 a').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropdown-content1').hide();
 });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.gap {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  background-color: #f47721;
  margin-top: 6%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.dropbt1 {
  background-color: #f47721;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f47721;
  /* min-width: 160px; */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content1 a {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content1 a:hover {
  background-color: #d86a1e
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="gap">
    <h3>Dropdownmenu</h3>

    <button class="dropbt1"><h3>please choose</h3></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1">
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down1</a>
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down2</a>
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that code. It's work , but only one time. If try to open the menu again , it will not work.

Comment: @ bruno2000 onHover it is showing when we mouse out it will hide so no need of js also as like your code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla javascript solution, that will work repeatedly. Note that due to the size of the closed menu and the position of the first link, clicking on the top half of the first link will result in the menu immediately re-opening (because the mouse is still hovering over the menu)

```js
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var clickedElement = e.target;
  if (clickedElement.classList.contains('specialLink')) {
    var menu = clickedElement.parentElement;
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    menu.classList.remove('touched');
    // then remove the style after giving it a chance to close so hovering will reopen the menu
    setTimeout(function() {
      menu.style = '';
    }, 200);
  }
  if (clickedElement.classList.contains('dropbt1')){
    var menu = clickedElement.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    if(!menu.classList.contains('touched'))
      menu.classList.add('touched');
    else
      menu.classList.remove('touched');
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.gap {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  background-color: #f47721;
  margin-top: 6%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.dropbt1 {
  background-color: #f47721;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f47721;
  /* min-width: 160px; */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content1 a {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content1 a:hover {
  background-color: #d86a1e
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content1, .dropdown-content1.touched {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropbt1{
  padding:0.5em;
  font-size:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="gap">
    <h3>Dropdownmenu</h3>

    <button class="dropbt1">please choose</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1">
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down1</a>
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down2</a>
      <a href="#" id="" class="specialLink">down3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that code. It's work fine on desktop but on mobile device it will not work. Did you have some idea?

Comment: Added support for mobile, button click will now toggle menu open/closed.

Comment: it's still reopen the menu after touch. can you try on your mobile? open this in desktop view on your mobile. Thank you