# Mouse onclick event target (Moving sidenavifation)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the sidebar to close when cicked outside the sidebar.

Right now the sidebar  closes when pressed inside the sidebar.

Please checkout the code below. I have a code sample below.

```js
  var mySidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  
  var navigationOpen = false;

  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
    document.getElementById("navIcon").style.visibility = "hidden";
    navigationOpen = true;
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("navIcon").style.visibility  = "visible";
    navigationOpen = false;
  }
    //Instead of when clicking on the nav to close
    // Make it close when clicking outside of the nav
    window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == mySidenav) {
        console.log("mouse click2")
        closeNav();
      }
      
      
  }
```

```css
.sidenav {
    padding-top: 60px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff000;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="navIcon" onclick="openNav()"> &#9776;</div>
  
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close the menu on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201156/close-the-menu-on-click)

Comment: Hi Rai, Not really I got the nav opening working when pressing  "open" and the closing working when pressing a link. I want to close the nav when clicking outside of the navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some style code and change bit of js code.
try it

```js
    var mySidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");

    var navigationOpen = false;

    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
        document.getElementById("navIcon").style.visibility = "hidden";
        navigationOpen = true;
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("navIcon").style.visibility  = "visible";
        navigationOpen = false;
    }
    //Instead of when clicking on the nav to close
    // Make it close when clicking outside of the nav
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == document.body) {
            closeNav();
        }
    }
```

```css
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .sidenav {
            padding-top: 60px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: 100%;
            width: 0;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #fff000;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
        #navIcon {
            padding: 4px 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="navIcon" onclick="openNav()"> &#9776;</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this

```
    if (event.target !== mySidenav) {
      console.log("mouse click2")
      closeNav();
      return;
    }
    openNav();
```

Comment: Hi @ian When using that I wont be able to open my nav

Comment: This edit makes it happen??? Sorry to ask, but I'm not running you're code

Comment: Hi Ian thanks again, unfortutantly It did not work.

Comment: Hi , I have updatd my questiona my code to make it a little bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
function Opennav(). 
   {document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.display = 
      'block'; // show
     }
function Closenav(){
    document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.display = 
        'none'; // hide
       }
```

Update your function:

```
 var sidenav= document.getElementById('mySidenav');


  window.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log("mouse click")
      if (event.target == sidenav) {
         console.log("mouse click2")
       closeNav();
       }
     }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, I want to use the animation to close the nav

Comment: @AttackTheWar I have updated the code . you can try it out and use '.style.width' instead of '.style.display' that I used here

Comment: Hi  , I have updatd my questiona my code to make it a little bit more clear

Comment: have you achieved your goal now, because its not really clear to me, you want it to sidebar to close when you click outside the sidebar, has it been achieved or not?

Comment: I want the sidebar to close when cicked outside the sidebar. This is not achieved.